# use "dot" in jupyter notebook and face " 'E:\Program' not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, environment-variables, dot

I use jypyter notebook to write code.
in my code, there are
`!dot -Tpng DecisionTree4.dot -o DecisionTree4.png`

after I installed dot by `conda install graphviz`, I have checked the place it is installed, it succeeds. the **dot.exe** located in **E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\comp47350py37\Library\bin\graphviz**

and then I just follow a guideline I found online to add the file location into my environment variables: **Variable** is "PATH" and **Value** is "E:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\comp47350py37\Library\bin\graphviz"

Now, my problems became:
**'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

And even I deleted the file path that I added into "PATH" and restarted my computer, it is still like this.

and also I have tried to use "progra~1" to replace "Program Files" and quoted 'Program Files' or all the path by single quotation(double isn't accepted by environment variables),
but all of them didn't work.

How could I solve this and make `!dot -Tpng DecisionTree4.dot -o DecisionTree4.png` work?

Comment: Quick guess probably some quotes missing in jupyter notebook path (check your settings).

Comment: hey, what does 'jupyter notebook path' mean? where could I find this? thx

Comment: I have no idea about jupyter so no idea whether or not it is present but a lot of programs store their own paths instead of using the default system path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install graphviz from http://www.graphviz.org/download/
and install it in "C" then add it to my environment variables

and in my anaconda terminal, use "condo uninstall graphviz" 
now it could work

Comment: Just to be clear, now, after you installed graphviz, does it work? Graphviz added it your PATH during installation. But my question is did your code work from jupyter notebook `!dot -Tpng DecisionTree4.dot -o DecisionTree4.png`

Comment: it could work from the juputer notebook